# Process the data received from bluetooth on android device

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am writing an application for a project, which detects light intensity and etc.
The application is supposed to send out command from android device to Arduino board and receive data from it. It serves as a bluetooth terminal, which I have already finished.

Now, I want to process the data I received.
I want:
1, graph the data;
2, only show data in xxx range.

Can anyone give me a hint to start? Like what method I should use or website I can look into?

Comment: Are you asking help on how to visualize the data? What do you mean by your 2nd requirement? If you want to only plot data in, say, range 0.4 to 0.8 then clip the values that fall outside this range. If you want to plot the graph within 100 pixels height then scale the data down accordingly.

Comment: it's more like sorting and graphing the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1, graph the data**: you can use java canvas methods or some library like http://www.android-graphview.org/ (which most likely uses canvas methods due to bad svg performance on mobile devices), or svg

**2, only show data in xxx range**: don't really get the question... why not simply drop the values on arduino(dont even sent them) or on andoid?

Besides that there is already an application which does exactly what you want to do (sending data to arduino and plotting data on android): https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sakulstra.androidbluetooth&hl=de and most likely some others (google for "android bluetooth graph")